# when i click the list view in the first class how will i get the datas stored in that list in my next activity??can someone help me out|?

Tags: android

```
public class GroceryList extends ListActivity {



                   Button btn_create;
    Cursor cursor;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn_create=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_create);
    btn_create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("rem", "msg");
            Intent in;
            in=new Intent(GroceryList.this,AddNote.class);
            startActivity(in);


        }
    });
```

//here am bringing a list view for this activity and am taking the contents from the database.
        String[] from = { Notes.NOTE_TITLE, Notes.NOTE_DATE }; 
        int[] to = { R.id.shoppingnoteText, R.id.dateText}; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(GroceryListContentProvider.NOTES_URI, null, null, null, null);

```
    CursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.addnotelist, cursor,from,to);
    setListAdapter(adapter); 
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 //TODO Auto-generated method stub


  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
 Intent intent;


 intent=new Intent(GroceryList.this,shoppinglist.class);


 startActivity(intent);


}


}
```

---

```
public class shoppinglist extends Activity {

TextView shop,date;
Cursor cursor;
Button save1;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shoppinglist);

    //Cursor cursor = managedQuery(GroceryListContentProvider.NOTES_URI, null, null, null, null); 

    shop=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.shop);
    date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
   save1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save1);
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(GroceryListContentProvider.NOTES_URI,null, null, null, null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
   String s=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Notes.NOTE_TITLE));
        shop.setText(s);
   Log.d("2", "msg");
   date.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Notes.NOTE_DATE)));

    save1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in;
            in=new Intent(shoppinglist.this,GroceryList.class);


            startActivity(in);              

        }
    });



}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data from activity one to activity two. use Intent to do so, for example if I want to pass index on listitemclick event:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 //TODO Auto-generated method stub


  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
 Intent intent;


 intent=new Intent(GroceryList.this,shoppinglist.class);
 intent.putExtra("SELECTED", position);

 startActivity(intent);


}
```

and get this position in second activity by using:

```
Intnet intent=getIntent();
int pos=intent.getInt("SELECTED", 0);
```

Comment: int pos=intent.getInt("SELECTED", 0);i have an error in this line......this is the error:The method getInt(String, int) is undefined for the type Intent

Answer (score 0):

to get data out from your list when an item is clicked, you me do it as below inside your *onListItemClick*:

```
Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
String title = c.getString(0);      //note's title
String date = c.getString(1);       //note's date
```

further, you can add your data in your Intent which is passed to next activity:

```
Intent intent;
intent=new Intent(GroceryList.this,shoppinglist.class);
intent.putExtra("data1", "this is custom data");   //adding string in intent
intent.putExtra("data2", 1234);   //adding int in intent
startActivity(intent);
```

and this is how you may retrieve it in your new activity:

```
String data1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data1");
int data2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("data2");
```

Comment: am getting an error at the adapter when i wrote it inside the onListItemClick

Comment: The adapter is probably the cursorAdapter that Waqas himself used, you expecting people to give you the full code on how it works?

Comment: i just updated my answer. You need to explicitly parse the type into cursor too: `Cursor c = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);`